# setting weekly time series from specific date

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following data and I am trying to set it to a time series format (weekly)

```
   ID       Wk  sales
1: 8024566 1584 73450 
2: 8042245 1586 75430 
3: 8044566 1589 77650 
4: 8045553 1590 72345
```

The data begins and ends on the following;

```
 wk
1583    2009-12-28 - 2010-01-03
1634    2010-12-20 - 2010-12-26
```

Which is in increments of 6 days not 7 (assuming Sunday is closed). I am trying to run set the `wk` column to date format to run some anaysis but cannot seem to correctly do it.

```
inds <- seq(as.Date("2009-12-28"), as.Date("2010-12-26"), by = "week")
set.seed(25)
myts <- ts(yogurt_drug$WEEK(length(inds)),
           start = c(2009-12-28, as.numeric(format(inds[1], "%j"))),
           frequency = 52)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in is.data.frame(data) : attempt to apply non-function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lacks of reproductibily : we don't have `yogurt_drug$WEEK` to test your problem.

However I think your problem comes from `yogurt_drug$WEEK(length(inds))`

The presence of `( )` implies the use of a function, but `yogurt_drug$WEEK` isn't a function, it's your dataframe.

Try this instead :

```
inds <- seq(as.Date("2009-12-28"), as.Date("2010-12-26"), by = "week")
set.seed(25)
w <- lubridate::week(ymd("2009-12-28","2010-12-26"))
y <- lubridate::year(ymd("2009-12-28","2010-12-26")) # this is overkill because obviously we know that the year of "2009-12-28" is 2009, but now you know this function exists too.
myts <- ts(yogurt_drug$WEEK,
           start = c(y[1],w[1]),
           end = c(y[2],w[2]),
           frequency = 52)
```

PS : if you want only the item number length(inds) of `yogurt_drug$WEEK` then use `yogurt_drug$WEEK[length(inds)]`

Edit : added the use of lubridate package (don't forget to install and load it) to get week and year from your start and end dates.

Comment: Thanks, this kind of allowed me to make a TS plot, however the date does not start in 2009. It starts in 1975... `Time Series:
Start = c(1975, 50) 
End = c(1977, 44) 
Frequency = 52 
 [1] 1584 1586 1589 1590 1590 1590 1591 1591 1591 1592 1594 1599 1605 1607 1607`

Comment: Ok it may come from your start in the ````ts```` function, you need to give a year + a week for start (and same for the end). Try to convert your start and end dates with the  ````lubridate:week```` function. I'll edit my anwser so you can copy paste my suggestion. ;)

Comment: Yes, works perfect! thanks `Time Series:
Start = c(2009, 52) 
End = c(2010, 52) 
Frequency = 52 `